# Extra characters on the end of the filename when using google drive SDK

Tags: google-drive-api

When we add files into a user's Google Drive the files show up and function perfectly.  However when the files are synced onto their mac, they end up with some strange guff at the end of the file names.  For example for code like this:

```rb
file = drive.files.insert.request_schema.new({
  'title' => "something.pdf",
  'description' => "A nice pdf for you",
  'mimeType' => content_type,
  'parents' => [{
    'kind' => 'drive#fileLink',
    'id' => 'our folder id'
  }]
})

media = Google::APIClient::UploadIO.new(file_on_disk, content_type)

client.execute(
  :api_method => drive.files.insert,
  :body_object => file,
  :media => media,
  :parameters => {
    'uploadType' => 'multipart',
    'alt' => 'json'})
```

Users would report filenames like `something.pdf20140910-4690-x8cnst-0`.  I assume this is due to the varying restrictions on filenames when comparing google drive and modern filesystems, however I'm not sure what I can do to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

The suffix is the result of the specific program used for synchronization. My guess is that it tries to display every file and maybe even several versions of the same file.
In drive you can have several files with the same name and for each file you can have multiple versions. You can try this by dropping the same file onto the website https://drive.google.com/#my-drive several times. New versions can be added by rightclicking the file, manage revisions, update revision. As you said conventional file systems can neither display multiple file system objects with the same name nor manage several versions of the same file. 
Depending on what you want to achieve, you can write a custom application which synchronizes your files with a folder on the local hard disk, or offers access similar to drive through a custom graphical user interface. 
If you are lucky, the synchronization program on the mac can be configured to display the files the way you want.

Maybe the program will even use the same file names as long as there are no other files with the same name. In that case, you should remove all duplicates. When you upload a file you should first check if a file with the same name exists. If it exists, you can either delete it before uploading the new file, or you can get its unique id and use it to overwrite the file.

Comment: I'm after a definitive answer as to in what circumstances the names end up with all the cruft on the end and how to avoid them.  We're building server side apps and can't mandate custom client-side software.

Comment: I see. Then, as I suggested, your best bet is to prevent and remove existing duplicate file names and file version history and check if the problem still occurs. I can only check Google Drive on windows, where it appends (NUMBER_OF_COPIES) to each file with the same name, except for the first. I don't think that there is an alternative in your case.